# Cisco N3k ipv4 table size

Tags: cisco-nexus

I read n3k-c3064pq datasheet and it seems it supports 16k ipv4, i want to know when i add one route for example "ip route 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.1.1" then it will consume 1 of 16k ipv4 table size? or does it cosnume more table size?
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's one prefix, consuming one of the entries in the 16k routing table.

You can find the scalability details here: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/scalability/935/cisco-nexus-3000-series-nx-os-verified-scalability-guide-935.html for NX-OS 9.3(5).